# Row highlight based on a cell value not hapenning in jQuery dataTable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to highlight a row in a dataTable based on a cell's value. But strangely, the css is not applied even if the condition to apply is met. The datatable is displying the data correctly but the row highlight is not hapenning. Please tell me where I'm going wrong. fyi..I'm using **client side** dataTables.

Thanks!!
Below is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
    //data to be added to dataTable is added into the html table before this line.
    oTableQ= $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bLengthChange":false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "columns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                null,
                    null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "visible": false }
        ],
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            if ( data[9] == "ACTIVE" ) {
              $(row).addClass('highlightRow'); //this line has no effect on the page even if the 'if' condition is satisfied.
              console.log(" row text is : "+ $(row).text() + "data at 9th column : " + data[9]);
            }
            },

            "iDisplayLength":10
             });
```

**CSS:**

```
    .highlightRow {
    background-color:   #ffaabb;
```

}

Comment: What version of datatables are you using? `createdRow` is a 1.10 feature, and the fact that you're initialising with lowercase 'dataTable` makes me think you're using 1.9

Comment: @markpsmith Yes,you are correct. I'm using jquery 1.9version. How to convert this code to jQuery 1.10?

Comment: @kkk, just include 1.10.x js/css versions. 1.10.x is backwards compatible and old code should work 1:1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fnRowCallback` for dataTables 1.9

```
...
  { "visible": false }
  ],
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
 if ( aData[9] == "ACTIVE" ){         
    $(nRow).addClass('highlightRow');
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I can replicate this problem described in the comment - am basically unable to apply the class to the  element. To get round it, you can apply the class to the child  elements.

try:

```
if ( aData[9] == "ACTIVE" ){ 
$(nRow).children().each(function (index, td) {
       $(this).addClass('highlightRow');
   });
}
```

Comment: I tired ur solution, it has no effect on my code, instead of 'createdRow' I put fnRowCallback , control enters the 'if' condition but it doesn't highlight the row.

Comment: Can you use Firebug or similar to see if the `highlightRow` class is being applied?

Comment: Yes, i put a console,log inside the 'if' condition and it's displayed on my console. So I'm sure that the if condition is being met. I've put the 'highlightRow' class inside the dataTables's css 'table.dataTable tbody tr'. Tried adding that class in another css also. Fpr both cases - no luck!!

Comment: Yes, but can you view the page source and see `<tr class="highlightRow">`?

Comment: I see two classes set for the particular row to be highlighted. Here is what I see in the source   'code' <tr class="odd highlightRow">. i do not want to set 'odd' class for that row which satisfies the 'if' condition I want only 'highlightRow' class to be set for it.

Comment: `odd` is the class applied by the datatable for the alternating row colours, and doesn't affect your class. So we've confirmed that the highlightRow is being applied, and presumably your CSS is being loaded correctly... have you added `!important` to the class?

Comment: Yes, I've added !important to that class, on the if condition, i now remove the odd class and add highlightRow class, and in generated source I see now only 'highlightRow' class applied to the affected row. but still surprisingly the background color is not reflected for that row!!!!

Comment: That's odd! I've updated my answer with a workaround

Comment: Thanks a lot for your workaround!! It's working wonderfully for me. Saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

`.highlightRow` is overruled by `table.dataTable tbody tr`, unless you use `!important` :

```css
.highlightRow {
    background-color: #ffaabb !important;
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/56abtw2t/**

or declare `.highlightRow` as an extension of the dataTables CSS (the correct way, in my opinion) :

```css
table.dataTable tbody tr.highlightRow {
   background-color: #ffaabb;
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/onaeyqkL/**

Comment: I tried your solution also that too has no effect on my 'DataTable'.

Comment: @kkk, this is because my answer is targeting 1.10.x, which I thought you were using (answered before you were admitting using 1.9.x, when people are showing 1.10.x code, I assume they use 1.10.x :). Here is a working 1.9.x version -> http://jsfiddle.net/tnoL173y/ I do not intend to delete the answer, since this issue is 100% certain to be asked for dataTables 1.10.x also.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is the way in which DT applies row highlighting. Here is the default css for table striping:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

According to this, the background color is applied to all of the td's of all of the odd rows in the table. This might seem illogical at first glance, but DT also offers the ability to do columnar striping as well which essentially requires the background color be applied at the td level.

So if one wants to apply a custom row background color based on a row (tr) class, one must do something along these lines:

```
.some-class, .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1).some-class > td, .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1).some-class > th {
    background  : #fafd96 !important;
}
```

One may then add/remove the "some-class" class to the tr based on the needs of one's particular use-case. Note that the variation above will apply the background to all rows (even or odd) which have the some-class class set.

This does not appear to be well documented at the DT website.

Note: This was verified on DT ver. 1.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
$('table#example')
.find("tr").find('td:eq(6):contains(null)').parent().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow') // row higlingting
```